# Popup Window unable to scroll in IE / FF / Safari. Works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

I have trouble getting the scrollbar to appear in the popup windows in the following code below:

I have added `scrollable=yes` after reading some solutions to the same question online, but still cannot do so.

```
print("<div id ='tableStatusReasons'>
                   <a href='#' style='color: ".$colorv."' onClick=\"window.open('volumeReport.php?case=".$case."&patient=".$patientID."','mywin','width=630,height=500,resizable=yes,scrollable=yes')\"><div class='volumeReport'><b>Volume Report Table</b><br>Status:   ".$vStatus." <br>Reason:   ".$vComment."</div></a>");
            print("<a href='#' style='color: ".$colors."' onClick=\"window.open('statsReport.php?case=".$case."&patient=".$patientID."','mywin','width=1400,height=650,resizable=yes,scrollable=yes')\"><div class='statisticsReport'><b>Statistics Report Table</b><br>Status:   ".$sStatus."<br>Reason:   ".$sComment."</div></a></div>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using CSS to add the scroll bar.

```
 <a href='#' style='color: ".$colorv."; overflow:scroll-y' ...
```